# How to exclude special characters in tesseract?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract and mcr.traineddata to read MICR numbers from the cheque. 
This is the part of the cheque that i want to read.

[image]

The below is the part of the text that has been detected from the image.

[image]

My question is..... 
**How do i exclude the special characters from the image?
Would training tesseract for the special characters be an option?
**

Except the special characters the rest of the numbers are getting detected.

My code

```
    let tesseract = G8Tesseract()
    tesseract.language = "mcr"
    tesseract.engineMode = .TesseractOnly
    tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = .Auto
    tesseract.maximumRecognitionTime = 60.0
    imageView.image = imageView.image?.g8_grayScale()
    imageView.image = imageView.image?.g8_blackAndWhite()    
    tesseract.image = imageView.image
    tesseract.recognize()
```

Comment: What about doing the reverse idea? Only accept wanted characters? `tesseract.charWhitelist = @"0123456789";` from https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/wiki/Using-Tesseract-OCR-iOS ?

Comment: @Larme ..... It returns the special characters as one of the values given in tesseract.charWhitelist...........

Answer (score 0):

I created a new traineddata file(my.traineddata). I trained the special characters to be recognized as 'X'. The more images we use the accurate the traineddata file. Then we can accordingly manipulate the recongized text.

Comment: Hello. I'm facing with same problem. Can you please help?